# R change title size in legend

Tags: r, plot, size, legend

I use the R base command "legend" to add a legend to a plot and I want the title of this legend to be bigger.
In the help it says:

> cex: character expansion factor *relative* to current ‘par("cex")’. 
>   Used for text, and provides the default for ‘pt.cex’ and ‘title.cex’.

But trying to change title.cex  doesn't work and throw a `unused argument` error.

Here an example:

```
plot(1:10,10:1)
legend("topright",title="I need that bigger",legend="points",pch=21)
```

Comment: `legend("topright",title="I need that bigger",legend="points",pch=21,cex=2)` ?

Comment: This also changes the size of the legend itself, I want to have only the title bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since R 4.2.0, you can use the argument `title.cex`:

```r
plot(1:10,10:1)
legend("topright",title="I need that bigger",legend="points", pch=21, title.cex = 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Change-the-text-size-of-the-title-in-a-legend-of-a-R-plot-td3482880.html) saying that:

> Looking at the code for legend, it looks like the same 'cex' value is
>   used for the text in the legend as the title.

And they say to change this:

```
text2(left + w/2, top - ymax, labels = title, adj = c(0.5,0), cex = cex, col = title.col)
```

With this:

```
text2(left + w/2, top - ymax, labels = title, adj = c(0.5,0), cex = title.cex, col = title.col)
```

I may end up doing this but if it's the only solution it looks to me like a bug, no?

Edit: This answer works indeed, thought the code of `legend` slightly changed in my version of R I changed this:

```
text2(left + w * title.adj, top - ymax, labels = title, adj = c(title.adj, 0), cex = cex, col = title.col)
```

by:

```
text2(left + w * title.adj, top - ymax, labels = title, adj = c(title.adj, 0), cex = title.cex, col = title.col)
```

and added:
`title.cex = cex` in the arguments of legend. It's working, though the size of the box surrounding the legend should be recalulate as if the title is too big it goes outside the box.

For those that just want to copy paste a version of legend that accept title.cex here it is:

```
legend  <- function (x, y = NULL, legend, fill = NULL, col = par("col"), 
    border = "black", lty, lwd, pch, angle = 45, density = NULL, 
    bty = "o", bg = par("bg"), box.lwd = par("lwd"), box.lty = par("lty"), 
    box.col = par("fg"), pt.bg = NA, cex = 1, pt.cex = cex, pt.lwd = lwd, 
    xjust = 0, yjust = 1, x.intersp = 1, y.intersp = 1, adj = c(0, 
        0.5), text.width = NULL, text.col = par("col"), text.font = NULL, 
    merge = do.lines && has.pch, trace = FALSE, plot = TRUE, 
    ncol = 1, horiz = FALSE, title = NULL, inset = 0, xpd, title.cex = cex,title.col = text.col, 
    title.adj = 0.5, seg.len = 2) 
{
    if (missing(legend) && !missing(y) && (is.character(y) || 
        is.expression(y))) {
        legend <- y
        y <- NULL
    }
    mfill <- !missing(fill) || !missing(density)
    if (!missing(xpd)) {
        op <- par("xpd")
        on.exit(par(xpd = op))
        par(xpd = xpd)
    }
    title <- as.graphicsAnnot(title)
    if (length(title) > 1)
        stop("invalid 'title'")
    legend <- as.graphicsAnnot(legend)
    n.leg <- if (is.call(legend))
        1
    else length(legend)
    if (n.leg == 0)
        stop("'legend' is of length 0")
    auto <- if (is.character(x))
        match.arg(x, c("bottomright", "bottom", "bottomleft",
            "left", "topleft", "top", "topright", "right", "center"))
    else NA
    if (is.na(auto)) {
        xy <- xy.coords(x, y)
        x <- xy$x
        y <- xy$y
        nx <- length(x)
        if (nx < 1 || nx > 2) 
            stop("invalid coordinate lengths")
    }
    else nx <- 0
    xlog <- par("xlog")
    ylog <- par("ylog")
    rect2 <- function(left, top, dx, dy, density = NULL, angle, 
        ...) {
        r <- left + dx
        if (xlog) {
            left <- 10^left
            r <- 10^r
        }
        b <- top - dy
        if (ylog) {
            top <- 10^top
            b <- 10^b
        }
        rect(left, top, r, b, angle = angle, density = density, 
            ...)
    }
    segments2 <- function(x1, y1, dx, dy, ...) {
        x2 <- x1 + dx
        if (xlog) {
            x1 <- 10^x1
            x2 <- 10^x2
        }
        y2 <- y1 + dy
        if (ylog) {
            y1 <- 10^y1
            y2 <- 10^y2
        }
        segments(x1, y1, x2, y2, ...)
    }
    points2 <- function(x, y, ...) {
        if (xlog) 
            x <- 10^x
        if (ylog) 
            y <- 10^y
        points(x, y, ...)
    }
    text2 <- function(x, y, ...) {
        if (xlog) 
            x <- 10^x
        if (ylog) 
            y <- 10^y
        text(x, y, ...)
    }
    if (trace) 
        catn <- function(...) do.call("cat", c(lapply(list(...), 
            formatC), list("\n")))
    cin <- par("cin")
    Cex <- cex * par("cex")
    if (is.null(text.width)) 
        text.width <- max(abs(strwidth(legend, units = "user", 
            cex = cex, font = text.font)))
    else if (!is.numeric(text.width) || text.width < 0) 
        stop("'text.width' must be numeric, >= 0")
    xc <- Cex * xinch(cin[1L], warn.log = FALSE)
    yc <- Cex * yinch(cin[2L], warn.log = FALSE)
    if (xc < 0) 
        text.width <- -text.width
    xchar <- xc
    xextra <- 0
    yextra <- yc * (y.intersp - 1)
    ymax <- yc * max(1, strheight(legend, units = "user", cex = cex)/yc)
    ychar <- yextra + ymax
    if (trace) 
        catn("  xchar=", xchar, "; (yextra,ychar)=", c(yextra, 
            ychar))
    if (mfill) {
        xbox <- xc * 0.8
        ybox <- yc * 0.5
        dx.fill <- xbox
    }
    do.lines <- (!missing(lty) && (is.character(lty) || any(lty > 
        0))) || !missing(lwd)
    n.legpercol <- if (horiz) {
        if (ncol != 1) 
            warning(gettextf("horizontal specification overrides: Number of columns := %d", 
                n.leg), domain = NA)
        ncol <- n.leg
        1
    }
    else ceiling(n.leg/ncol)
    has.pch <- !missing(pch) && length(pch) > 0
    if (do.lines) {
        x.off <- if (merge) 
            -0.7
        else 0
    }
    else if (merge) 
        warning("'merge = TRUE' has no effect when no line segments are drawn")
    if (has.pch) {
        if (is.character(pch) && !is.na(pch[1L]) && nchar(pch[1L], 
            type = "c") > 1) {
            if (length(pch) > 1) 
                warning("not using pch[2..] since pch[1L] has multiple chars")
            np <- nchar(pch[1L], type = "c")
            pch <- substr(rep.int(pch[1L], np), 1L:np, 1L:np)
        }
        if (!is.character(pch)) 
            pch <- as.integer(pch)
    }
    if (is.na(auto)) {
        if (xlog) 
            x <- log10(x)
        if (ylog) 
            y <- log10(y)
    }
    if (nx == 2) {
        x <- sort(x)
        y <- sort(y)
        left <- x[1L]
        top <- y[2L]
        w <- diff(x)
        h <- diff(y)
        w0 <- w/ncol
        x <- mean(x)
        y <- mean(y)
        if (missing(xjust)) 
            xjust <- 0.5
        if (missing(yjust)) 
            yjust <- 0.5
    }
    else {
        h <- (n.legpercol + (!is.null(title))) * ychar + yc
        w0 <- text.width + (x.intersp + 1) * xchar
        if (mfill) 
            w0 <- w0 + dx.fill
        if (do.lines) 
            w0 <- w0 + (seg.len + x.off) * xchar
        w <- ncol * w0 + 0.5 * xchar
        if (!is.null(title) && (abs(tw <- strwidth(title, units = "user", 
            cex = cex) + 0.5 * xchar)) > abs(w)) {
            xextra <- (tw - w)/2
            w <- tw
        }
        if (is.na(auto)) {
            left <- x - xjust * w
            top <- y + (1 - yjust) * h
        }
        else {
            usr <- par("usr")
            inset <- rep_len(inset, 2)
            insetx <- inset[1L] * (usr[2L] - usr[1L])
            left <- switch(auto, bottomright = , topright = , 
                right = usr[2L] - w - insetx, bottomleft = , 
                left = , topleft = usr[1L] + insetx, bottom = , 
                top = , center = (usr[1L] + usr[2L] - w)/2)
            insety <- inset[2L] * (usr[4L] - usr[3L])
            top <- switch(auto, bottomright = , bottom = , bottomleft = usr[3L] + 
                h + insety, topleft = , top = , topright = usr[4L] - 
                insety, left = , right = , center = (usr[3L] + 
                usr[4L] + h)/2)
        }
    }
    if (plot && bty != "n") {
        if (trace) 
            catn("  rect2(", left, ",", top, ", w=", w, ", h=", 
                h, ", ...)", sep = "")
        rect2(left, top, dx = w, dy = h, col = bg, density = NULL, 
            lwd = box.lwd, lty = box.lty, border = box.col)
    }
    xt <- left + xchar + xextra + (w0 * rep.int(0:(ncol - 1), 
        rep.int(n.legpercol, ncol)))[1L:n.leg]
    yt <- top - 0.5 * yextra - ymax - (rep.int(1L:n.legpercol, 
        ncol)[1L:n.leg] - 1 + (!is.null(title))) * ychar
    if (mfill) {
        if (plot) {
            if (!is.null(fill)) 
                fill <- rep_len(fill, n.leg)
            rect2(left = xt, top = yt + ybox/2, dx = xbox, dy = ybox, 
                col = fill, density = density, angle = angle, 
                border = border)
        }
        xt <- xt + dx.fill
    }
    if (plot && (has.pch || do.lines)) 
        col <- rep_len(col, n.leg)
    if (missing(lwd) || is.null(lwd)) 
        lwd <- par("lwd")
    if (do.lines) {
        if (missing(lty) || is.null(lty)) 
            lty <- 1
        lty <- rep_len(lty, n.leg)
        lwd <- rep_len(lwd, n.leg)
        ok.l <- !is.na(lty) & (is.character(lty) | lty > 0) & 
            !is.na(lwd)
        if (trace) 
            catn("  segments2(", xt[ok.l] + x.off * xchar, ",", 
                yt[ok.l], ", dx=", seg.len * xchar, ", dy=0, ...)")
        if (plot) 
            segments2(xt[ok.l] + x.off * xchar, yt[ok.l], dx = seg.len * 
                xchar, dy = 0, lty = lty[ok.l], lwd = lwd[ok.l], 
                col = col[ok.l])
        xt <- xt + (seg.len + x.off) * xchar
    }
    if (has.pch) {
        pch <- rep_len(pch, n.leg)
        pt.bg <- rep_len(pt.bg, n.leg)
        pt.cex <- rep_len(pt.cex, n.leg)
        pt.lwd <- rep_len(pt.lwd, n.leg)
        ok <- !is.na(pch)
        if (!is.character(pch)) {
            ok <- ok & (pch >= 0 | pch <= -32)
        }
        else {
            ok <- ok & nzchar(pch)
        }
        x1 <- (if (merge && do.lines) 
            xt - (seg.len/2) * xchar
        else xt)[ok]
        y1 <- yt[ok]
        if (trace) 
            catn("  points2(", x1, ",", y1, ", pch=", pch[ok], 
                ", ...)")
        if (plot) 
            points2(x1, y1, pch = pch[ok], col = col[ok], cex = pt.cex[ok], 
                bg = pt.bg[ok], lwd = pt.lwd[ok])
    }
    xt <- xt + x.intersp * xchar
    if (plot) {
        if (!is.null(title)) 
            text2(left + w * title.adj, top - ymax, labels = title, 
                adj = c(title.adj, 0), cex = title.cex, col = title.col)
        text2(xt, yt, labels = legend, adj = adj, cex = cex, 
            col = text.col, font = text.font)
    }
    invisible(list(rect = list(w = w, h = h, left = left, top = top), 
        text = list(x = xt, y = yt)))
}
```

Comment: It is not really a bug but I guess there were no need of this when the function was written. If you want to do more fancy graphs you might switch to `ggplot2`

Comment: yes I know for the `ggplot2` thing, but this one thing that maybe I should have mention from the beginning: *I don't want to use it* :D

Comment: also if not a bug, why then say:  "Used for text, and provides the default for ‘pt.cex’ and ‘title.cex'  " in the legend. Sounds misleading to me. I will accept my answer for now.